# Team Foundation Server 2017 update 3 not syncing with Active-Directory

Tags: active-directory, synchronization

TFS 2017 update3 is not syncing with Active directory. The users are not refreshing in Access control screen under server settings.

When trying to add user typing domain name it is not fetching any users list.

Answer (score 1):

Changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. TFS Job Agent is responsible for running this sync, by default this run once an hour.

You could try to restart TFS Job Agent service to see whether it helps. Also, check the article below to see whether it helps you:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx